# Spring boot properties with array

Tags: spring-boot, properties

With an `application.properties` like that

```
application:
  api:
    clients:
      api1:
        url: http://url1
      api2:
        url: http://url2
        basicAuth:
          username: user2
          password: password2
```

I can do

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.api")
@Data
public class ApiProperties {

    private Map<String, Client> clients;

    @Data
    public static class Client {
        private String url;
        private BasicAuth basicAuth;
    }

    @Data
    public static class BasicAuth {
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }

}
```

And it is working.

But is there a way of retrieving only one client ?  So In place of

```
private Map<String, Client> clients;
```

I'd like to have something like

```
@Value("${application.api.clients['api1']}")
private Client client1;
```

I tried multiple ways of writing it but I always have `Could not resolve placeholder...`

Is there a solution ?

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github/gitlab ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is not possible with nested properties or hierarchal properties.

```
@Value("${application.api.clients['api1']}")
private Client client1;
```

But you can try this if you want to retrieve only one client.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.api.clients")
@Data
public class ApiProperties {

    private Client api1;

    @Data
    public static class Client {
        private String url;
        private BasicAuth basicAuth;
    }

    @Data
    public static class BasicAuth {
        private String username;
        private String password;
    }

}
```